# Exporting multiple flash animations as android APK

Tags: android, air, flash-builder, flash

I recently found out that flash (swf) files can be exported into an android native app (.apk) instllation coupled with the adobe air core, so this means a great opportunity to bring the animator's flash files into my native app without modifying them (Great!!) - Yet it brought me to a number of questions:

1. Can I open the exported apk and, for example, take out the nice libCore.so and embed it in my apk?
2. Can I insert more than one SWF file in one export, and then invoke each with intents or another mechanism?

The idea is to use the animation generated by the animator guy (which provides me with SWF files) and show them in my Android native app. Let's say there are 15 animations, and I each time I want to run one of them. I don't want multiple installations, that's why I want the exported apk mixed with my app (is it possible?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the first question, but in regards to number 2, you will need to include the swfs during project compilation (usually by including an "assets" folder created in the source folder).

Within your main application, you could use a loader to load in a swf and add it as a display object.  Each time you need to show another swf, stop and remove the current one, and load again.

Comment: Ok, so when you say 'application' you mean air/flash application?

Comment: Yes, within the main actionscript file that will drive the air/flash application.

Answer (score 1):

Took me long time to find that out (probably because I am not a flash developer...) there is a better way to integrate flash natively and cross-platform. Didn't test it yet but it looks the way to go: http://www.openfl.org